# Tracing a 2D polygon in 3D space - Appropriate algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

I'm currently working on a problem where I need to properly order (using something like a right-hand rule) the nodes that make up a planar polygon in 3D space.  My idea thus far is to construct a transformation matrix to convert the nodes to an x-y plane, then use a Graham scan.  I need to ensure that the user enters only convex polygons, so if I find any "internal" nodes, I know the polygon is concave and can throw an error.  In addition to checking for convexity, the sorting procedure of the Graham scan will order the nodes for me.

I am not terribly familiar with optimized geometry algorithms.  Does this seem like a appropriate/efficient process?  Or is there a better way to:

1) Order the nodes of the polygon by some rule (e.g. RH rule) and
2) Ensure that the planar polygon (which may not be in the x-y plane) is convex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a very good solution. Here's how to implement it to ignore numerical inaccuracy.

```
- take any 3 points; these determine the plane, rotate appropriately
- check that abs(z)<THRESHOLD for all z-coordinates, now you can ignore them
- perform Graham scan which is O(n log(n)) time
- return order, else throw error if results.size < #points (non-convex)
```

You might wish to choose 3 points sufficiently far apart, or a combination of many points (still has its issues), and make the THRESHOLD some fraction of the max distance between.

With a few assumptions, this is **provably as good as you can do** asymptotically, because otherwise, you could use this to perform a comparison sort in less than `O(n log(n))` time, which we know is impossible without extra knowledge (the problem mapping would be to place each element X of an unsorted array at position [X,X^2] in the plane plus a point at [0,max^2]).

Comment: The bound only applies if you restrict yourself to comparisons (or algebraic decision trees, which more general, but the O(n log (n)) bound still applies to them).  Integers have a rich, exploitable structure for example. See http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/608/examples-of-the-price-of-abstraction/665#665  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/608/examples-of-the-price-of-abstraction/2146#2146

Comment: I already said this and much more. =) "without extra knowledge"